# Comparing Unicode Chars in Java (e.g. Greek Delta)

Tags: java, string, unicode, char

I have to check if the first char of a string is a greek delta. An easy task. Or not?
I was surprised that the following code didn't work:

```
char first = myString.charAt(0);
boolean isDelta = first =='Δ';
```

How to solve my problem? The only way I have found is to compare the hex String:

```
 String unicodeForDelta = "394";
...
...
 char first = myString.charAt(0);
 boolean isDelta = unicodeForDelta.equals(Integer.toHexString(first));
```

Is this ok or there are better ways?

Comment: The Greek delta is not a character that needs to be represented with a surrogate pair. Surrogate pairs are only for Unicode characters that do not fit in a single `char`. `first` must be containing something else than the character you expect. Try printing out the actual character code of `first` to see what it really is: `System.out.println((int) first);`. Also try `System.out.println((int) 'Δ');` and see what the difference is.

Comment: When I run this code it's working :---                                                             String str = "Δsecond";
  System.out.println(str.charAt(0) == 'Δ');
  System.out.println( str.charAt(0) == (char)916);

Comment: Are you _sure_ that the encoding you have configured your compiler to use when reading the source file is correct (i.e. matches the encoding that the file is actually saved in)? Does it work if you represent the delta as a Unicode escape `'\u0394'` instead of the literal character?

Comment: Good suggestion. It has to due with the encoding of ma java/class file. If I write as a Unicode escape '\u0394' it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

well it works:

```
public class Delta {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String delta = "Δ";
        String str = "this string contains a Δ in it";

        char deltaChar = delta.charAt(0);

        System.out.println("str contains Δ: " + str.contains(delta));

        System.out.println((int) deltaChar);
        System.out.println((int) 'Δ');

        boolean isDelta = (deltaChar == 'Δ');

        System.out.println("is delta: " + isDelta);

        System.out.println("Integer.toHexString(deltaChar) = " + Integer.toHexString(deltaChar));

        System.out.println("Integer.toHexString(deltaChar) = " + Integer.toHexString(deltaChar));

        System.out.println( "\\u" + Integer.toHexString(deltaChar | 0x10000).substring(1) );

        String hexVal = "394";
        System.out.println("hexVal.equals(Integer.toHexString(deltaChar)) = " + hexVal.equals(Integer.toHexString(deltaChar)));
        System.out.println("hexVal == Integer.toHexString(deltaChar) = " + (hexVal == Integer.toHexString(deltaChar)));
    }
}
```

prints:

```
str contains Δ: true
916
916
is delta: true
Integer.toHexString(deltaChar) = 394
Integer.toHexString(deltaChar) = 394
\u0394
hexVal.equals(Integer.toHexString(deltaChar)) = true
hexVal == Integer.toHexString(deltaChar) = false
```

make sure your source is saved as UTF.
Note that String `==` check if it is the same reference: that is the exact same object in memory

For comparing the **content** of an Object you should use `equals`

Comment: Ok, this could be the problem. But, if a look with the debugger I see a String starting with 'Δ'. If I ask the Hex value of the first char I get "394", which is the value of a capital greek Delta. So, why is the comparison c=='Δ' false?

Comment: Yeah ok, true for String, but char is a primitive type and can be compared with ==

Comment: yes and it works as you see in the code above `boolean isDelta = (deltaChar == 'Δ');` the output of `System.out.println("is delta: " + isDelta);` is `is delta: true`; post your complete code...what's the value of `myString`?